# Pattern for sending events from parent to child component in Blaze

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze, eventemitter

Let's assume we have the following abstract setup:

```
<template name="parent">
  {{> child childProps}}
</template>
```

and a helper function:

```
Template.parent.helpers({
  childProps() {
    const instance = Template.instance();
    return {
      // whatever props we want
    };
  }
});
```

I am wondering what's the best way to allow `parent` component to send events to it's `child` component.

There are at least two methods I can think of:

1. Don't send events and only control the child through `props`. This is probably what some people would recommend doing. The problem is that this approach requires `child` to track it's `Template.currentData()` context and react accordingly to potential changes, which makes the implementation much more complicated and error prone.
2. Create `instance.emitter = new EventEmitter()` in the `onCreated` hook and pass it to the `child` data context, so that it can add listeners for certain events. This seems more flexible and less error prone, but still a little complicated as the child needs to properly manage listeners cleanup not only in it's lifecycle methods, e.g. `onDestroy` but also as a result  to current data context changes.

Does anyone have other ideas how this pattern could be implemented in `Blaze`? Is there some kind of standard way of doing it, or maybe some packages that already solve this problem?